# Loading ssh_keys in ansible to run svn+ssh

Tags: svn, ansible

I need to write a task using svn+ssh to checkout a repositiory.

Here is how i was able to do it manually which works perfectly

```
ssh-add /home/my_user/.ssh/id_rsa
svn co svn+ssh://svnserver/repo/src /path/to/checkout
```

However using the below task seems to be failing because my keys aren't been loaded

```
- name: Checkout code
  subversion:
   repo: svn+ssh://svnserver/repo/src
   dest: /path/to/checkout
  become_user: my_user
  become: no
```

When i run an ssh-add -L after loading the keys manually, i do see my keys are loaded. However ansible doesn't seem to be loading my keys when it runs the subversion task which is causing the task to fail with the following.

```
Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'svn+ssh:/svnserver/repo/src
```

Any idea how to run this so that my user keys are loaded when the task is run?

Comment: Do you use `local` connection type for your subversion task? Do you execute ansible-playbook from the same shell as your agent is executed in?

Answer (score 0):

I have the strong feeling that your manual `ssh-add` adds the ssh key to the agent of **your** user, so running `svn co svn+ssh://svnserver/repo/src /path/to/checkout` while **you** are logged in will work, but for Ansible you run the task as **my_user** (`become_user: my_user`), and for **my_user** you did not add the private key yet.

Could you see if it helps to switch to my_user, and then execute the `ssh-add` command?

However, honestly, I am not a big fan of the ssh-agent. I find it more transparent to have and rely on my own ssh config file.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Actually my_user is also the ansible user running the tasks.